# confusion in union concept

Tags: c++, c, unions

```
#include<stdio.h>

union node {
     int i;
     char c[2];
};

main() {

    union node n;
    n.c[0] = 0;
    n.c[1] = 2;
    printf("%d\n", n.i);
    return 0;
}
```

I think it gives `512` output becouse c[0] value stores in first byte and c[1] value stores in second byte, but gives `1965097472`. Why ?.
I compiled this program in codeblocks in windows.

Comment: Try setting `n.i` to `0` first, in order to set the other two bytes to 0.  It will probably work like you expect, though technically it is like Luchian says, still undefined behavior, so you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your union allocates four bytes, starting off as:

```
[????] [????] [????] [????]
```

You set the least two significant bytes:

```
[????] [????] [0x02] [0x00]
```

You then print out all four bytes as an integer. You're not going to get `512`, necessarily, because anything can be in those most significant two bytes. In this case, you had:

```
[0x75] [0x21] [0x02] [0x00]
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the least significant bytes are {2, 0}; aliasing behavior depends on the implementation.

Comment: Furthermore the number quoted above is 0x75210200 so you can see the 2 last significant bytes have been set as expected while the most significant bytes have rubbish values in them.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: hmm actually I will have to ask for a specific reference. In what case would the code the OP posted _not_ do as I have specified in this answer (assuming little endian 4-byte ints, which if you change, would not make a program crash but would just cause a different result)? What compiler and set of compiler flags would cause this to do something truly unexpected?

Comment: It doesn't matter. C++ is guided by the standard, not by compilers. Compilers can be wrong.

Comment: Assuming a specific behavior that is against the set of rules of the language because it works on all compilers you tested it on is wrong.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: can you point me to the relevant portion of the standard? been trying to google it

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I thought union was defined as: all members share the same space. the size of the union is the size of the largest member. thus, if you have a 4-byte member and a 2-byte member, the 2-byte member will take up the first 2 bytes of the 4 byte member. setting the 2-byte member will thus change the 4 byte member in an entirely predictable manner, given you know the endianness and such, with no chance of it causing a crash...

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with a quote. I posted a question.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, will come back to this answer when it's clear whether the behavior is undefined or not.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, in C this is not UB, but the value of the uninitialized bytes is unspecified, and can thus be anything, as explained here. UB then only occurs if the value is a trap representation for the type. Modern architectures usually don't have trap representations for integer types. AFAIR, the C++ standard has different rules and for C++ it is UB, so it is free to do whatever it likes. There are good chances that this "whatever it likes" is what is given by the C standard. (compiler implementors can't gain much by implementing two different strategies, here)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: no worries, ty for looking into it more. I'm curious now, too. we'll see how your question pans out

Comment: @JensGustedt "_UB then only occurs if the value is a trap representation for the type._" Reading an **uninitialised** `int` with the bit-pattern of `0` is not UB?

Comment: @curiousguy, exactly. Most modern cpu don't have trap representations for integer values, so all you get is just a "random" `int`. The only integer data type that I know of that has usually padding bits is `_Bool`, there you may have surprises how a random bit pattern is interpreted.

Comment: @JensGustedt "_Most modern cpu don't have trap representations for integer values,_" I didn't asked about trap representation, or CPU (old or new). I asked if reading a variable that isn't initialised **is defined behaviour in C**. This is a C question, not a CPU question. "_The only integer data type that I know of that has usually padding bits is _Bool_" I am surprised that `_Bool` has padding bits. "_there you may have surprises how a random bit pattern is interpreted_" how?

Comment: @curiousguy, the technical term of the C standard is indeterminate value, such a value is either "unspecified" or a trap representation. Modern CPU (and the C implementations on top of it) use 2's complement without trap representation. So on modern systems this is a unspecified value, or said differently, any bit pattern that the compiler sees fit, commonly just garbage.

Comment: For `_Bool` this is different. You only have two values (0 and 1) but at least 8 bit. If an unitialized `_Bool` is read and contains a bit pattern that is different from these two, it could be interpreted according to the LSB, a conversion from `int` to `_Bool` could take place, or a signal could be raised. And there is no guarantee that the compiler does this consistently.

Answer (score 3):

Because undefined behavior. Accessing an `union` member that wasn't set does that, simple as that. It can do anything, print anything, and even crash.

Comment: But union allocates 4 bytes, and in first and second byte it stores 0 and 2 respectively. We stores two values at different location. How can it give output like this?

Comment: @algoh again - undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: It would have worked if you had stored 0 in the last two bytes. But you didn't.

Comment: @MrLister or not. It's UB people.

Comment: Indeed. It will print 131072 instead of 512 on some computers. Or in some esoteric cases, 2.

Comment: By the way, I don't want to sound pedantic, but isn't "implementation dependent" something else than "undefined behaviour"?. For instance, you said it can crash, but is it really possible for a program to crash when printing an uninitialised int?

Comment: @MrLister It can crash, of course. That's what the standard says. Anything can happen with UB. It probably won't though.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Don't know about C++, but in C, it's not undefined behaviour, just the two bytes not corresponding to the `char[2]` member have unspecified values when reading the `int` member. That might lead to the read value being a trap representation (but for `int`, that's extremely unlikely).

Comment: @MrLister "_but is it really possible for a program to crash when printing an uninitialised int?_" That question doesn't make sense. The definition of UB is that **the compiler is free to assume** that your program does not do anything that doesn't have defined behaviour. Take dereferencing a null pointer, f.ex. The compiler can assume your program never does that.

Comment: (...) So when it sees `*p` (in an evaluated context), the compiler can assume that `p` isn't null at this point. So if you just do `{ *p; if (p == 0) f(); }` the compiler can assume that the `p == 0` is false and remove the whole `if (p == 0) f();` part. Another example of UB in C is (I believe) reading an uninitialised integer. The compiler can just assume you are doing that.

Comment: @DanielFischer When is a variable initialised in C? Shall we say "initialised variable" or "initialised object"? or lvalue?

Comment: @curiousguy 1) I wasn't talking about NULL pointers, and 2) if your compiler does that, you should throw it away and start using a standards compliant one.

Comment: @MrLister "_I wasn't talking about NULL pointers_" But **I** am talking about null (not "NULL") pointer. "_if your compiler does that_" does what?

Comment: If your compiler removes `if (p == 0) f();` when p is a pointer. You may be confusing pointers and references. Also, you are taking this thread off-topic. And the value is definitely spelled NULL in C, not null.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior is, well... undefined.

We **can** try to answer why a specific result **was** given (and the other answers do that by guessing compiler implementation details), but we **cannot** say why another result **was not** given. For all that we know, the compiler could have printed 0, formatted your hard drive, set your house on fire or transferred 100,000,000 USD to your bank account.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `int` is likely to be at least 4 bytes (not 2, like it was in the good ol' days). To let the sizes match, change the type of `i` to `uint16_t`.

Even after this, the standard does not really permit setting one union member, and then accessing a different one in an attempt to reinterpret the bytes. However, you could get the same effect with a `reinterpret_cast`.

```
union node {
    uint16_t i;
    uint8_t c[2];
};

int main() {
    union node n;
    n.c[0] = 0;
    n.c[1] = 2;
    std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(&n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `int`is compiled as a 32 bit number, little endian. By setting the two lower bytes to 2 and 0 respectively and then reading the int you get 1965097472. If you look at the hexadecimal representation 7521 **0200** you see your bytes again, and besides it is undefined behaviour and part of it depends on the memory architecture of the platform the program is running on.